# Duplicate Gulp Vinyl Stream with PassThrough- `TypeError: Invalid non-string/buffer chunk`

Tags: node.js, stream, gulp

In Node, I am trying to duplicate a gulp vinyl stream using `Passthrough`. I get `TypeError: Invalid non-string/buffer chunk` when attempting `c = fileStream.pipe(b);`

I suspect it may be because `fileStream` is a gulp vinyl stream.

```
var pass = require('stream').PassThrough;

function duplicateStream(fileStream) {
    b = new pass();
    c = fileStream.pipe(b);
    return c;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to clone a gulp stream, you can just use `gulp-clone`. This task will write all of the single JS files to the `out` directory, as well as a concatenated `bundle.js` in the same directory.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var clone = require('gulp-clone');
var merge = require('merge-stream');

gulp.task('default', function () {
    var scripts = gulp.src('assets/**/*.js');

    var bundle = scripts.pipe(clone())
      .pipe(concat('bundle.js'));

    // Merge the streams together, then write them to the out folder
    return merge(scripts, bundle).pipe(gulp.dest('out'));
});
```

https://github.com/mariocasciaro/gulp-clone

Comment: I would of never of known  that there was a `clone()` method on through2's file argument. Is this a public method? I didn't see it anywhere in the api.

Comment: It's a vinyl method (vinyl is gulp's virtual file abstraction) https://github.com/wearefractal/vinyl#clone